# Magento Mobile HTML5 theme

Tags: html, magento, magento-1.7

I downloaded and followed the instructions for the magento plugin for HTML5 mobile templates (http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/magento-community-mobile-html5-theme-6529.html) and installed all as Expected into the latest version of stable magento (installed tonight)

Below is the picture of my default config design themes section:

http://s3.postimg.org/8nku3rc1v/Screen_Shot_2013_05_14_at_01_45_05.png

Below is the picture of the connect install screen:

http://s3.postimg.org/guctvc24j/Screen_Shot_2013_05_14_at_01_45_37.png

Yet when looking at the site from my mobile - all I see is the normal desktop site. I have no overrides in place as far as I can tell.

Whats wrong!?

Answer (score 1):

I found out the problem and got it fixed myself.

Basically the install had put the theme not under default package but enterprise.

This means I added a new exception to the design -> package which looked like :

iphone|Android to value enterprise and then under the theme and template and css etc its matched expression iphone|Android and value of mobile.

That then makes it all work :)